# Get selection from controlled MUI Autocomplete with async data and react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm using a controlled autocomplete field in a form.
The data comes from my redux store; if the array is empty, I initialize it in a useEffect:

```
  const collectionList = useSelector((state) => state.collectionList);
  const { collections } = collectionList;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (collections.length === 0) dispatch(listCollections());
  }, []);
```

Here is the Autocomplete input :

```
const ControlledAutocomplete = ({ options, control, name, label }) => {
  return (
   <Controller
     render={({ field }) => (
       <Autocomplete
         {...field}
         options={options}
         getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name || ""}
         isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
         renderInput={(params) => (
           <MyTextField {...params} label={label} />
         )}
       />
     )}
    onChange={([, obj]) => obj.id}
    name={name}
    control={control}
    defaultValue=""
  />
)}
```

And finally in the form :

```
<ControlledAutocomplete
  control={control}
  name="collection"
  options={collections}
  label="Collection"
 />
```

I'm having this errors in the console :

> useAutocomplete.js:219 MUI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.
> None of the options match with `{}`.
> You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to customize the equality test.

...probably when the data is still not available? And I'm also unable to select a value from the options... I'm kinda lost here, all the doc I found seems in a language from another galaxy! A bit of help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: How are you initializing collectionList at the state?

Comment: collectionList comes from the redux store; it is an object as { collections: [], loading: bool, success: bool }. I initialize its value on useEffect with the dispatch method as shown on the first lines... the problem I am having is not about autocomplete showing data (it does!) but more on how to select a value from the list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so... i got this one working doing like this:

```
const ControlledAutocomplete = ({ options, control, name, label, setValue }) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      render={({ field }) => (
        <Autocomplete
          {...field}
          onChange={(ev, val) => setValue(name, val)}
          options={options  || []}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name || ""}
          isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => {
            if(value.id) return option.id === value.id
            return true
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <MyTextField {...params} label={label} />
          )}
        />
      )}
      name={name}
      control={control}
    />
  );
}
```

and I'm using it in the form :

```
<ControlledAutocomplete
  control={control}
  name="category"
  options={categories}
  label="Category"
  setValue={setValue}
/>
```

with initialization of 'categories' in the useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (categories.length === 0) dispatch(listCategories());
}, []);
```

and the hook from react-hook-form :

```
const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  formState: { errors },
  control,
  reset,
  setValue,
} = useForm({
  defaultValues: defaultValues,
  resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
});
```

This one is not easy; not documented enough I think... it compiles without errors or warnings but I have no idea if it is the proper way to do! Anyway, I hope it helps...